# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'before_request'

Tags: python, machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, nlp

I am new to the Google Natural Language Processing Library...and trying to get entities from a text file locally but keeps getting error. I've tried even the sample code from Google but the error is the same.

Here's my code:

```
import six
from google.cloud import language
from google.cloud.language import enums
from google.cloud.language import types



def entities_text(text):
    """Detects entities in the text."""
    client = language.LanguageServiceClient(credentials='cred.json')

    if isinstance(text, six.binary_type):
        text = text.decode('utf-8')

    # Instantiates a plain text document.
    document = types.Document(
        content=text,
        type=enums.Document.Type.PLAIN_TEXT)

    # Detects entities in the document. You can also analyze HTML 
    with:
    #   document.type == enums.Document.Type.HTML
    entities = client.analyze_entities(document).entities

    # entity types from enums.Entity.Type
    entity_type = ('UNKNOWN', 'PERSON', 'LOCATION', 'ORGANIZATION',
               'EVENT', 'WORK_OF_ART', 'CONSUMER_GOOD', 'OTHER')

    for entity in entities:
        print('=' * 20)
        print(u'{:<16}: {}'.format('name', entity.name))
        print(u'{:<16}: {}'.format('type', entity_type[entity.type]))
        print(u'{:<16}: {}'.format('metadata', entity.metadata))
        print(u'{:<16}: {}'.format('salience', entity.salience))
        print(u'{:<16}: {}'.format('wikipedia_url',
            entity.metadata.get('wikipedia_url', '-')))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open('test.txt', 'r') as text:
        text = text.read()
    ent = entities_text(text)
    print(ent)
```

Here's the stacktrace:

```
AuthMetadataPluginCallback " 
<google.auth.transport.grpc.AuthMetadataPlugin object at 
0x7f6973b4a668>" raised exception!
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/user/Documents/CODE/venv/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/grpc/_plugin_wrapping.py", line 79, in __call__
   callback_state, callback))
File "/home/user/Documents/CODE/venv/lib/python3.6/site- 
   packages/google/auth/transport/grpc.py", line 77, in __call__
   callback(self._get_authorization_headers(context), None)
File "/home/user/Documents/CODE/venv/lib/python3.6/site- 
   packages/google/auth/transport/grpc.py", line 61, in 
   _get_authorization_headers
   self._credentials.before_request(
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'before_request'
```

How do I get it to return the entities please?

Comment: Please correct the code indentation, as we don't know if it is an error in your code or just bad formatting inside stackoverflow. I see at least 2 strange cases: the line `with open('...') as text` and also the solo `with` statement inside the function `def entities_text(text):`

Comment: Also, please add the full error stacktrace. Contrary to popular belief, we usually cannot guess what the error is and why it is happening.

Comment: Updated the stacktrace @Ralf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `credentials` argument does not accept a str, but a `Credentials` object. Create one from your JSON file and pass it in.

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
'cred.json')
```

[From this doc page](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#service-account-private-key-files)

The hint here is this line: `self._credentials.before_request`. You pass in `credentials`, the `LanguageServiceClient` object puts it in private variable `_credentials` and tries to call a method on it. Since your string doesn't have that method it blows up.

Comment: Thanks very much @dwagnerkc. Really appreciate your time.